# Excel Formula - Countifs + Indirect + Match across multiple rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count records that are located in different rows which:

- are within a certain date range eg. starting from >= 01/01/2017
- are within the same month as defined above eg. < 31/01/2017
- have records within a range across multiple rows, row numbers must be obtained via `MATCH` by finding the row of the cell that contains "Negative Comment 1" and `MATCH` the row number of the cell that contains "Negative Comment 5" (eg. "Negative 1" is in Row 220, "Negative 5" is in row 224, hence the rance would be I220:AZZ224 which spans 5 rows)

Formula looks like this:

```
=IFERROR(COUNTIFS(
// starting date
'MED-FB-YTD'!$I$18:$AZZ$18,">="&DATE(YEAR(E3),MONTH(E3),"1")-1,

// end date
'MED-FB-YTD'!$I$18:$AZZ$18,"<"&DATE(YEAR(E3),MONTH(E3),"31"),

// define range between Negative Comment 1 to 5 and count all records that are not empty
INDIRECT("'MED-FB-YTD'!$I$"&MATCH("Negative Comment 1",'MED-FB-YTD'!$C:$C,0)&":$AZZ$"&MATCH("Negative Comment 5",'MED-FB-YTD'!$C:$C,0)),"<>"),

"ERR")
```

The problem is here

```
// define range between Negative Comment 1 to 5 and count all records that are not empty
INDIRECT("'MED-FB-YTD'!$I$"&MATCH("Negative Comment 1",'MED-FB-YTD'!$C:$C,0)&":$AZZ$"&MATCH("Negative Comment 5",'MED-FB-YTD'!$C:$C,0)),"<>"),
```

The formula works fine if I change the range to count from 5 rows to 1 row (eg. change from `I220:AZZ224` to `I220:AZZ220`), which leads me to believe that the `countifs()` formula doesnt like to count cells across multiple rows, which in turn however is unlikely as I used `countifs()` before and did just that.

Right now, I am always getting the `#value` error. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Sample data below:

MED-FB-YTD (data source):

[image: data]

Display form:

[image: form]

Comment: Your problem is that `COUNTIFS` strictly requires that all the `criteria range` parameters be of exactly the same dimensions. You probably need a different approach. Worth considering is `SUMPRODUCT`.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something missing in the formula which you have pasted at the end (I mean in your problematic line).

Can you re-share your formula?